# VLOOKUP Formula places Apostrophe in front of text and generates Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am writing a macro which inserts some formulas into a column array. I am trying to automate a weekly process, so the input files are variable and are selected through the `msoFileDiaglogFilePicker` application.

```
Dim wb_Final As Workbook, nameFinal As String
Set wb_Final = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Final_Directory)
nameFinal = wb_Final.Name



Dim wb_Summary As Workbook, nameSummary As String
Set wb_Summary = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Summary_Directory)
nameSummary = wb_Summary.Name

wb_Summary.Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet 1")
.Range("AT4:AT5000").Formula = "=IF(OR(AX1=""Open"",AX1=""Won"",AX1=""Won - Pending""),""Yes"",""No"")"
.Range("AU4:AU5000").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(W:W,LOVs!H:I,2,FALSE)"
.Range("AV4:AV5000").Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A:$A,'[" & nameFinal & "]DATA'!$A:$AK,34,FALSE),0)=0,"",VLOOKUP($A:$A,'[" & nameFinal & "]DATA'!$A:$AK,34,FALSE))"
.Range("AW4:AW5000").Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AV:$AV,'[" & nameFinal & "]DATA'!$AH:$CX,48,FALSE),0)=0,"",VLOOKUP($AV:$AV,'[" & nameFinal & "]DATA'!$AH:$CX,48,FALSE))"
'....More formulas similar to above
End With
```

The first two formulas get placed into the cells and compute with no problem.

The third formula gets placed into the cells as a text with an apostrophe in the front of it in excel. (i.e. `'=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP...`)

The fourth formula generates a *Run-time error '1004'*

I have tried all the different formula types:

`.Formula
.FormulaR1C1
.FormulaLocal
.FormulaR1C1Local`

And still receive the same error.

I think I am experiencing a similar issue as stated in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744128/using-vlookup-in-vba-to-reference-another-excel-file), but I'm not if I can use the `Application.Vlookup` function without redefining all the arrays and column references in my current VLOOKUP functions (which would take a VERY long time).

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Sounds like it could be a formatting issue to me.  I would delete the column and insert it again to reset the formatting.  If I'm wrong you only wasted a couple of seconds, if I'm right, easy fix!  Though I do see that you are using an apostrophe in the formula as @Napoli noted.  That will for sure cause a problem.

Comment: I just tried this. Still experience the same error :( When I leave the formula as is with the apostrophe, the formula shows up as a text. When I go into the cell and remove the apostrophe from the front of the formula, it asks if I want to correct the formula. When the excel corrects the formula, it performs the VLOOKUP. The problem is - I cant figure out what the difference is from the formula I inputted (minus the apostrophe in front) and the corrected formula.

Comment: Consider `Debug.Print`ing the fourth formula, copy the output from the immediate window, paste formula into any cell and see if Excel displays the same error (if it does, see if a particular character range is highlighted in the formula bar).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use apostrophes in formulas; instead use quotation marks, and in your case, you'll need to escape it like you did in your prior formulas, example:

```
VLOOKUP($A:$A,""[" & nameFinal & "]DATA""!$A:$AK,34,FALSE)
```

Comment: I just tried this. Still experience the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1") '>== or Sheet1 depending on actual name
    .Range("AW4:AW5000").Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AV:$AV,[" & nameFinal & "]DATA!$AH:$CX,48,FALSE),0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP($AV:$AV,[" & nameFinal & "]DATA!$AH:$CX,48,FALSE))"
End With
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(

Comment: What happens? Is there an error message? Does it still error on this line?

Comment: After making the changes you suggested, I Still experiencing the same error as above: third formula populates into the array as a text (with an apostrophe in front) and the fourth formula produces a Run-time error '1004'